# Not send email when there is no data in the selected data range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code which is sending a data from a defined range of Google sheet. This data range will be auto populated using formulas.
Once this will auto populate and data will fill then email will be sent for which I have set triggers.

I have got script which is sending emails with data in the range but want to send emails only when there is data in the fields.

```
function email() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var bulk = ss.getSheetByName("Bulk");
  var lastrow = bulk.getLastRow();
  var data = bulk.getRange(1, 2, lastrow,2).getValues();  
  var tableData = '<TABLE style="border-collapse:collapse;"border = 1 cellpadding = 5 ><th style=color:blue>First data</th><th style=color:green>Second data</th>'

  for (var i =1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var d1=data[i][0]==''?'empty':data[i][0];
    var d2=data[i][1]==''?'empty':data[i][1];
    tableData+="<tr><td style=color:blue>"+d1+"</td><td style=color:green>"+d2+"</td></tr>"
  }
  tableData+="</table>";

  MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
                    "Your report", "html only", {htmlBody: tableData});
}
```

Once the above script runs then it should only send email if there is data else nothing. Data will be populated using formulas. I will use time trigger to schedule the run time.

Comment: what have you tried for checking if the d1 or d2 is empty or not? I do not see a if statement there.

Comment: d1 or d2 is empty or not is adding "empty" word in the sheet. So, if I don't have data it is adding empty word and sending email. It would be great you can help in avoiding empty cells and once all the cells are empty it should not send email. I am new and still learning, if you can modify the code and help me with complete edited code then it would be very helpful.

Comment: To explain little more in detail I want to terminate this function MailApp.sendEmail if data range is empty.

Answer (score 0):

### Incorporate in your code a boolean variable that `empty` that will be set to false in case content is found in the data:

```
  var empty=true;
  for (var i =1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][0]!=""||data[i][1]!=""){
      empty=false;
    }
    var d1=data[i][0]==''?'empty':data[i][0];
    var d2=data[i][1]==''?'empty':data[i][1];
    tableData+="<tr><td style=color:blue>"+d1+"</td><td style=color:green>"+d2+"</td></tr>"
  }
  tableData+="</table>";
  if(empty==false){
   Logger.log('not empty');
   MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
                    "Your report", "html only", {htmlBody: tableData});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out with this below code, this will send email only if data is present in that column.

```
function CCemail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var bulk = ss.getSheetByName("testRollcallremaining");
  var lastrow = bulk.getLastRow();
  var data = bulk.getRange(1, 4, lastrow,2).getValues();  
  var tableData = '<TABLE style="border-collapse:collapse;"border = 1 cellpadding = 5 >'
  var rollcal_len=bulk.getRange("D1:D").getValues().filter(String).length;

  var rollcall_data=bulk.getRange("D1:D"+rollcal_len).getValues();
  Logger.log(rollcall_data)
  if(rollcal_len>1){
  for (var i =0; i < rollcal_len; i++) {
    var d1=rollcall_data[i];

    tableData+="<tr><td style=color:blue>"+d1+"</td></tr>"
  }
  tableData+="</table>";




  MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
                    "Rollcoll Pending List", "html only", {htmlBody: tableData});
  }else{ Logger.log("Roll bCk Data is 0")}
}
```